# Trying to install watchdog

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, watchdog, python-watchdog

I couldn't understand how to install watchdog module to vscode, I have updated my pip but when I write pip install watchdog, it says

> "Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in c:\users\nazım\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.1.2)."

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm if it installed via the shell utilities. In your terminal, type in `watchmedo --help`.
Source: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/0.5.4/

There's also a VS code extension called watchdog. You can access that by opening VS code, typing in command + shift + x, and searching for watchdog. I only see workspace watchdog, though, so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.